# C# Make float out of ints

Tags: c#

```
int a = 6;
int b = 9;

float combined; //I want this to equal 0.69
```

How to make a float equal to lets say 0.69 using **int a** and **int b** as the first and second decimal?

Comment: Can't you just do the math? `float combined = (a / 10F) + (b / 100F);`

Comment: How would you do it with pencil and paper?  What logical process would you follow to perform this calculation?  What happens when you try to translate that process into code?

Comment: could also do `float.TryParse(String.Format("0.{0}{1}", a, b), out combined);` but in both examples if `a` or `b` are larger than 10 it would have more than 2 decimal places.

Comment: What if `a` has a value like `42`?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a weird scenario, so I wouldn't be opposed to simply creating the desired string and parsing it.

```
    int a = 6;
    int b = 9;
    float c = float.Parse($".{a}{b}");
```

You can also convert the ints to floats and perform this algorithmically but then you will need to handle rounding.

EDIT: Added some sample output (dotnetcore 3.1; win10 21h2)

```
    int a = 6;
    int b = 9;

    float c1 = float.Parse($".{a}{b}");
    // 0.69

    float c2 = (a / 10F) + (b / 100F);
    // 0.69000006

    double c3 = (a / 10D) + (b / 100D);
    // 0.69
```

Comment: I suppose technically since we're doing digit mapping it ought to be `decimal` instead of `double`